# How to bind to a guice provider by annotation?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, cucumber, e2e-testing

I'm using `guice` in my project, and I run an E2E test with cucumber.

I want to bind a selenium webdriver to

1) usually to `ChromeWebDriver`

2) for members annotated with `@Firefox` I want to bind to `FirefoxWebDriver`

I wrote this code

```
binder.bind(WebDriver.class).annotatedWith(Firefox.class).toProvider(WebDriverFirefoxProvider.class).in(ScenarioScoped.class);
```

and

```
    @Provides
    @ScenarioScoped
    public WebDriver provideWebDriver() {

 return new ChromeDriver();
}
```

FireFox instance is indeed initialized, but:

1) Chrome is initialized as well. How can I suppress this only when `@Firefox` annotation is applied?

All my used member in this scenario are with `@Firefox`

2) more than one `firefox` is initialized even though I add `@scenarioScoped.class`. How can I make only one init?

3) how can i close this `firefoxe` instance only if my cucumber test has passed successfully?